# Can "trust" and "dismiss" be used without an object?

Tags: transitivity

a. You are a bit too quick to dismiss.

b. Do not be so quick to dismiss.

---

c. You have a tendency to trust.

d. You trust too much.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think 'dismiss' and 'trust' are transitive verbs and need an object. I don't think they can be used without an object.

There is another thread about this issue, but I didn't really find it helpful. I think verbs such as 'smoke', 'read', and 'eat' can be both transitive and intransitive. However, I am not sure that 'dismiss' and 'trust' can be used intransitively.

Comment: i don't think they can be used without an object either; but you can say that someone is _too dismissive_ or _too trusting_.

Comment: ***To trust*** works better than ***to dismiss*** with no explicitly-specified object, but I think it would be pedantic in the extreme to dismiss [***People can be quick to dismiss** and you need to work extra hard to make sure your social enterprise is as professional as it can be in its presentation.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quick+to+dismiss+and+you%22) as somehow "incorrect". Having looked at a few sentences from that text, I'd say that writer is *exceptionally* competent - it all seems very well phrased to me.

Comment: You can find that "trust" has an intransitive meaning [from a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trust). However, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss), Oxford and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dismiss) all consider "dismiss" to be transitive only, even though your first two sentences sound perfectly natural to me.